# Vue JS 3, Quasar 2 app- Keep alive not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework, quasar

I cant seem to get keep-alive working in a Quasar v2 (Vue v3) project.

I have seen other answered questions about this on SO and tried all of them that are Vue3 vintage.

Here are some of the various efforts in my App.vue

```
<template>

  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>

</template>
```

based on other answers I have tried pretty much all combinations of substituting the below

```
    <component :is="Component" :key="$route.fullPath"></component>
    
    <component :is="Component" :key="$route.name"></component>

    <keep-alive include="MyPageComponent">
```

MyPageComponent is a page component that contains a filterComponent with a datePicker and an listComponent that displays a list of filtered items.

What I am expecting to happen is I follow the route into MyPageComponent, change the filter date and the list items change.

Then I navigate away from the MyPageComponent and when I return the items and filterDate are as they were when I left.

Everything works in my project apart from the filterDate and list are not preserved between navigations.

Is this the correct expectation?

If so, what else could I look at? All the answers I have seen are fairly straightforward.

The only other thing I can think of is that when instantiated, MyPageComponent passes a hard coded starting date value to the filterComponent.